# What vim features available only upon compilation?

Tags: vim

There seems to be an extensive set of features that can be enabled and disabled from within one's .vimrc, but there seems to be a number of features that has to be specified upon compiling vim's source. For example, Arabic support and I'm not sure but some syntax highlighting and autocompletion?

I could be mixing up some plugin features with native features, but every time I read something on compiling vim from source I come across the mandatory "Oh and don't forget to add this argument to get that feature that you can't get otherwise".

Comment: It totally depends on who packaged vim for you. Each OS / distro is likely to choose different defaults.

Comment: *All* vim feature are available only upon compilation; somebody had to compile the `vim` executable you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim can be compiled as a small executable with only the bare minimum features needed for quick edits, that's the default vim you get on most unixes, or as a big executable with many more features needed for programing.

The compile-time features required by commands and functions are listed in the doc under each command/function with specific requirements. No feature needed means the command is available no matter what features were enabled at compile time.

You can read about the subject in

```
:help :version
```